# Framework/Library for binding HTML screen elements to Javascript structures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Experts,

I'd like create a rich client application using HTML, JQuery, and Javascript. Is there a framework or library out that that makes it easy to bind or translate between HTML page elements like forms or divs to Javascript structures?

Example: Let's say I want to manage a class 'Car' in my client app. The car has certain properties which I'd like to store in a Javascript variable. The 'Car' should have an edit dialog that let's you edit the properties (e.g. color, model). When the properties are updated in the edit dialog, I also want to edit the Javascript variable properties so I can perform updates on the server-side via ajax.

I can do this manually in javascript or jquery but I'm wondering if there's a framework or library that does it automagically.

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://backbonejs.org/ ... http://backbonetutorials.com/why-would-you-use-backbone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the number of javascript MV* frameworks with view-model binding capabilities like [CanJS](http://canjs.us/), [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [others](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/)